# How to assure single value is passed to formula or function?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to structure things up, I use named ranges often. When these are vectors, I feel uncertain whether the formula or function the vector is passed to will pick a single value (that of the row or column of the calling cell), or use the entire vector.

1. What's the easiest way of inferring whether a formula will try to pick a single value or not out of a vector argument?
2. Using the VALUE() function I get the single value, but it is long and makes the formulas harder to read. Is there a shorter formulation or a more elegant way?

I think the attached Picture illustrates my question:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force implicit intersection for a function by preceding its arguments with +

```
=MAX(+Vec1_,+Vec2_)
```

AFAIK there is no easy way of telling (apart from testing or guessing) which arguments for which function have been setup to handle implicit intersection and which have not: but you can make a pretty good guess by thinking about how the function is supposed to work:

```
VLOOKUP(lookupVal,LookupRange, colnum)
```

lookupVal and Colnum are expected to be single values and so will do implicit intersection, but LookupRange is expected to be multiple values so will not.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot; a plus sign; that is indeed both shorter and more elegant (now I just wonder why no one told me this before). This was very useful!